# Проблема при отправке ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Возникла ошибка при отправке `ajax` запроса:

> $ajax is not defined.

вот код скрипта:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
     $("#butF").click(function(){
        var name=$("#name").val();
        var mail=$("#e-mail").val();
        var txt=$("#txt").val();
        var em=$("#em").val();
        if(name===""){
        alert("ВВЕДИТЕ ИМЯ");
        return false;}
        if(txt===""){
        alert("ВВЕДИТЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ");
        return false;}
        if(em!=="1@2 (не изменяйте это поле)"){
        alert("ОШИБКА ВВОДА");
        $("#em").val("1@2 (не изменяйте это поле)");
        return false;}
        if(mail.indexOf('@')<0){
        alert("ВВЕДИТЕ EMAIL");
        return false;}
      var mes=$("#contact").serializeArray();
      $ajax({type:"POST",
       url:"php/contact.php",
       data:mes,
       success:function(){
          alert("ВАШ ЗАПРОС ПРИНЯТ. СПАСИБО");
          $("#name","#e-mail","#txt").val("");}
     });
     });
});
```

Comment: у вас ошибка. Должно быть `$.ajax`

Answer (score 1):

`$ajax` заменить на `$.ajax`. это не переменная же